# Does "fostered out of a local tribe" mean the same thing as "fostered in a local tribe" here?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

This context comes from the TV show "*The Leftovers*". The speakers are located in Australia.

"*One of Grace’s kids was **fostered out of a local tribe**. He loved boats. When his family found out he died, some of his cousins came down here to leave a mark. Grace told them to strip the church. Took the wood from the church to make a tombstone for his little boy, a memorial.*"

Does "*out of*" in this context mean...

(informal) From a thing or or place as a source, place of origin etc. [from 12th c.]
*He ate out of a big bowl.
Turns out he's some rapper out of New York called Buster Bigmouth.*

...?

In this case the Grace's child would be raised **in** some tribe because she couldn't do it for some reason.

Comment: The child was taken out of the tribe and placed with a foster family. If Grace was the foster parent, it would make sense to call the child one of her kids , as in kids she fostered not kids she gave birth to.

Comment: If they have meant in they would have used it. He came out of Hollywood, not Bollywood. [some action verbs] + out + of + [a] place

Comment: Grace took in a foster kid. who came from (out of) a tribe. His birth cousins paid their respects after his death, because he came out of their tribe and they felt connected.

Comment: Fostering moves a kid temorarily out of one home and into another.

Comment: OP seems to imply that it was Grace's own child who was being brought up by a tribe.  In that case I would expect **fostered out to**, not **of**.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - all fostering is necessarily 'temporary', given that children reach adulthood, but you can have short- and long-term fostering. the latter continuing until the child 'ages out' of the care system.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I assumed that "fostered out of a local tribe" is similar to "The company operates out of offices in London.". In the first case the kid was fostered in the tribe & the second the company conducts business in London. Do you understand my rationale?

Comment: Yes, but the analogy isn't correct. A child sent to live with another family is _fostered out to_ that family - going _out_ of its own family _to_ the other. As previous commenters have assumed, _fostered out of a tribe_ suggests that Grace was foster-parent to a child from the tribe.

Comment: Does "One of the kids out of the local tribe was fostered by Grace" mean the same? This construction sounds natural and I don't have a problem with understanding the meaning. Also, can anyone confirm if the definition I provided in the OP is relevant here?                                                    
(informal) From a thing or or place as a source, place of origin etc. [from 12th c.] 
Turns out he's some rapper out of New York called"